# UDP server and JSON parser script

Tags: python, multithreading, json, socket, serial-port

I am a Python beginner and wrote a script which should run on a Raspberry PI as a UDP server. It reads and writes to a serial device and has to process and forward JSON strings.

Because there is relatively much functionality included and I don't like cross compiling, I was too lazy to write a C program but instead chose Python. To avoid serial read/write blocks I even used threads. However I noticed that sometimes I get timeouts.

Are there some methods to make this script maybe faster or even to guarantee timings? Additionally I am open for style tips.

```
# Make this Python 2.7 script compatible to Python 3 standard
from __future__ import print_function
# For remote control
import socket
import json
import serial
# For sensor readout
import logging
import threading
# For system specific functions
import sys
import os
import time

# Create a sensor log with date and time
layout = '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(filename='/tmp/RPiQuadrocopter.log', level=logging.INFO, format=layout)

# Socket for WiFi data transport
udp_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
udp_sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 7000))
client_adr = ""

# Thread lock for multi threading
THR_LOCK = threading.Lock()

#pySerial
pySerial = 0

def init_serial(device_count = 10):
  counter   = 0
  baud_rate = '115200'
  while counter < device_count:
    com_port  = '/dev/ttyACM%d' % (counter)
    try:
      # rtscts=1 is necessary for raspbian due to a bug in the usb/serial driver
      pySerial = serial.Serial(com_port, baud_rate, timeout=0.1, writeTimeout=0.1, rtscts=1)
    except serial.SerialException as e:
      logging.debug("Could not open serial port: {}".format(com_port, e))
      print ("Could not open serial port: {}".format(com_port, e))
      com_port = '/dev/ttyUSB%d' % (counter)
      try:
        # rtscts=1 is necessary for raspbian due to a bug in the usb/serial driver
        pySerial = serial.Serial(com_port, baud_rate, timeout=0.1, writeTimeout=0.1, rtscts=1)
      except serial.SerialException as e:
        logging.debug("Could not open serial port: {}".format(com_port, e))
        print ("Could not open serial port: {}".format(com_port, e))
        if counter == device_count-1:
          return False, 0
        counter += 1
      else:
        return True, pySerial
    else:
      return True, pySerial

#chksum calculation
def chksum(line):
  c = 0
  for a in line:
    c = ((c + ord(a)) << 1) % 256
  return c

def send_data(type, line):
  # calc checksum
  chk = chksum(line)
  # concatenate msg and chksum
  output = "%s%s*%x\r\n" % (type, line, chk)
  try:
    bytes = pySerial.write(output)
  except serial.SerialTimeoutException as e:
    logging.error("Write timeout on serial port '{}': {}".format(com_port, e))
  finally:
    # Flush input buffer, if there is still some unprocessed data left
    # Otherwise the APM 2.5 control boards stucks after some command
    pySerial.flushInput()  # Delete what is still inside the buffer

# These functions shall run in separate threads
# recv_thr() is used to catch sensor data
def recv_thr():
  global client_adr
  ser_line = ""
  try:
    while pySerial.readable():
      # Lock while data in queue to get red
      THR_LOCK.acquire()
      while pySerial.inWaiting() > 0:
        # Remove newline character '\n'
        ser_line = pySerial.readline().strip()
        try:
          p = json.loads(ser_line)
        except (ValueError, KeyError, TypeError):
          # Print everything what is not a valid JSON string to console
          print ("JSON format error: %s" % ser_line)
          # Send the string to the client after is was flagged
          nojson_line = '{"type":"NOJSON","data":"%s"}' % ser_line
          if client_adr != "":
            bytes = udp_sock.sendto(nojson_line, client_adr)
        else:
          logging.info(ser_line)
          if client_adr != "":
            bytes = udp_sock.sendto(ser_line, client_adr)
      THR_LOCK.release()
  # Terminate process (makes restarting in the init.d part possible)
  except:
    os.kill(os.getpid(), 15)

# trnm_thr() sends commands to APM2.5
def trnm_thr():
  global client_adr
  msg = ""
  try:
    while pySerial.writable():
      try:
        # Wait for UDP packet from ground station
        msg, client_adr = udp_sock.recvfrom(512)
      except socket.timeout:
        # Log the problem
        logging.error("Read timeout on socket '{}': {}".format(adr, e))
      else:
        try:
          # parse JSON string from socket
          p = json.loads(msg)
        except (ValueError, KeyError, TypeError):
          logging.debug("JSON format error: " + msg.strip() )
        else:
          # remote control is about controlling the model (thrust and attitude)
          if p['type'] == 'rc':
            com = "%d,%d,%d,%d" % (p['r'], p['p'], p['t'], p['y'])
            THR_LOCK.acquire()
            send_data("RC#", com)
            THR_LOCK.release()

          # Add a waypoint
          if p['type'] == 'uav':
            com = "%d,%d,%d,%d" % (p['lat_d'], p['lon_d'], p['alt_m'], p['flag_t'] )
            THR_LOCK.acquire()
            send_data("UAV#", com)
            THR_LOCK.release()

          # PID config is about to change the sensitivity of the model to changes in attitude
          if p['type'] == 'pid':
            com = "%.2f,%.2f,%.4f,%.2f;%.2f,%.2f,%.4f,%.2f;%.2f,%.2f,%.4f,%.2f;%.2f,%.2f,%.4f,%.2f;%.2f,%.2f,%.4f,%.2f;%.2f,%.2f,%.2f,%.2f,%.2f" % (
              p['p_rkp'], p['p_rki'], p['p_rkd'], p['p_rimax'],
              p['r_rkp'], p['r_rki'], p['r_rkd'], p['r_rimax'],
              p['y_rkp'], p['y_rki'], p['y_rkd'], p['y_rimax'],
              p['t_rkp'], p['t_rki'], p['t_rkd'], p['t_rimax'],
              p['a_rkp'], p['a_rki'], p['a_rkd'], p['a_rimax'],
              p['p_skp'], p['r_skp'], p['y_skp'], p['t_skp'], p['a_skp'] )
            THR_LOCK.acquire()
            send_data("PID#", com)
            THR_LOCK.release()

          # This section is about correcting drifts while model is flying (e.g. due to imbalances of the model)
          if p['type'] == 'cmp':
            com = "%.2f,%.2f" % (p['r'], p['p'])
            THR_LOCK.acquire()
            send_data("CMP#", com)
            THR_LOCK.release()

          # With this section you may start the calibration of the gyro again
          if p['type'] == 'gyr':
            com = "%d" % (p['cal'])
            THR_LOCK.acquire()
            send_data("GYR#", com)
            THR_LOCK.release()

          # Ping service for calculating the latency of the connection
          if p['type'] == 'ping':
            com = '{"type":"pong","v":%d}' % (p['v'])
            if client_adr != "":
              bytes = udp_sock.sendto(com, client_adr)

          # User interactant for gyrometer calibration
          if p['type'] == 'user_interactant':
            THR_LOCK.acquire()
            bytes = pySerial.write("x") # write a char into the serial device
            pySerial.flushInput()
            THR_LOCK.release()

  # Terminate process (makes restarting in the init.d part possible)
  except:
    os.kill(os.getpid(), 15)

# Main program for sending and receiving
# Working with two separate threads
def main():
  # Start threads for receiving and transmitting
  recv=threading.Thread(target=recv_thr)
  trnm=threading.Thread(target=trnm_thr)
  recv.start()
  trnm.start()

# Start Program
bInitialized, pySerial = init_serial()
if not bInitialized:
  print ("Could not open any serial port. Exit script.")
  sys.exit(0)
main()
```

Comment: why use debugging  and logging? You can add a handler which outputs to `stdout`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Style**

- `init_serial` is quite hard to follow. It took me a while to realize that code in a nested try-except is not a retry. Factor out the identical code into a function. Also, there is no need to return a success status in a separate boolean: returning None is just fine, in a boolean context it is False:

  For example:

  ```
  def init_serial(device_count = 10):
      baudrate = '115200'
      for counter in range (device_count):
          port = open_port('/dev/ttyACM%d' % (counter), baudrate)
          if port:
              return port
          port = open_port('/dev/ttyUSB%d' % (counter), baudrate)
          if port:
              return port
      return None

  def open_port(portname, baudrate):
      try:
          return serial.Serial(portname, baudrate, timeout=0.1, writeTimeout=0.1, rtscts=1)
      except serial.SerialException as e:
          logging.debug("Could not open serial port: {}".format(portname, e))
          print ("Could not open serial port: {}".format(portname, e))
  return None
  ```
- Remote control definitely must be factored out in a separate function. Better yet, create a function for each type an dput them in a dictionary indexed by possible values of `p['type']`.

  For example:

  ```
  type, com = form_command[p['type']](p)
  send_data(type, com)
  ```
- **Synchronization**

  Your code serializes reads and writes to the serial port. *Do they need to be serialized?*

  In any case, the serial receiver locks the port for unnecessary long time: the heavyweight operations such as JSON parsing, network sends, exception handling and logging have nothing to do with the serial port access, and shall not execute while the lock is acquired.

  For a network receiver, the lock is available for a minuscule amount of time, which may very well lead to a starvation.

  If you do not have a strong reasons for locking (and I do not see any), just get rid of it. If I am wrong, and there are reasons, minimize the locking time to an absolute necessity.

Comment: I don't know why, but the script is crashing if I don't use thread locks.

Comment: How does it crash? Is there an exception (and if so what is the trace)?

Comment: Unfortunately I was not getting an exception or trace-back with my script. The problem seems to be weird for me. I just added these thread locks, because I thought that read/write access on a serial device is not possible when I started to make my script threaded and noticed these crashes. But it would be nice if there is a clean way to remove them.

Comment: I believe it could be because of the exceptions I included in the thread functions:
If I read and write at the same time I raise maybe these exceptions:

     "except:
      os.kill(os.getpid(), 15)"

But how to make the script safe and nice without these exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

This is the new version. This script would potentially work without locks. However the traffic is too high and the strings get cut without locks. 
So I decided to keep them but limited to 4 ms. This script seems not to suffer from latency problems (in the 100-250 ms range) anymore. Average is 5 ms and peaks at 30-40 ms.

Now handling multiple clients with a set is possible. I use monit for process management. What would be left is to define good kill conditions for both threads.

```
# Make this Python 2.7 script compatible to Python 3 standard
from __future__ import print_function
# For remote control
import socket
import json
import serial
# For sensor readout
import logging
import threading
# For system specific functions
import sys
import os
import time

# Create a sensor log with date and time
layout = '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(filename='/tmp/RPiQuadrocopter.log', level=logging.INFO, format=layout)

# Socket for WiFi data transport
udp_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
udp_sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 7000))
udp_clients = set()
pySerial    = None

# Thread lock for multi threading
THR_LOCK = threading.Lock()

def init_serial(device_count = 10):
  baudrate = '115200'
  for counter in range (device_count):
    port = open_port('/dev/ttyACM%d' % (counter), baudrate)
    if port:
      return port
    port = open_port('/dev/ttyUSB%d' % (counter), baudrate)
    if port:
      return port
  return None

def open_port(portname, baudrate):
  try:
    # Set timeouts to 4 ms. 3.5 ms is the measured bias when long msg get cut!
    return serial.Serial(portname, baudrate, timeout=0.004, writeTimeout=0.004)
  except serial.SerialException as e:
    logging.debug("Could not open serial port: {}".format(portname, e))
    print ("Could not open serial port: {}".format(portname, e))
  return None

def chksum(line):
  c = 0
  for a in line:
    c = ((c + ord(a)) << 1) % 256
  return c

def ser_write(type, line):
  chk = chksum(line)
  output = "%s%s*%x\r\n" % (type, line, chk)                            # Concatenate msg and chksum

  if pySerial is not None:
    THR_LOCK.acquire()
    try:
      bytes = pySerial.write(output)
    except serial.SerialTimeoutException as e:
      logging.error("Write timeout on serial port")
    except serial.SerialException as e:
      logging.error("Write exception serial port")
    finally:
      pySerial.flushInput()                                             # Workaround: free write buffer (otherwise the Arduino board hangs)
    THR_LOCK.release()

def udp_write(msg, clients):
  for client in clients:
    bytes = udp_sock.sendto(msg, client)

def make_command(p):
  type = p['type']

  # remote control is about controlling the model (thrust and attitude)
  if type == 'rc':
    com = "%d,%d,%d,%d" % (p['r'], p['p'], p['t'], p['y'])
    ser_write("RC#", com)

  # Add a waypoint
  if type == 'uav':
    com = "%d,%d,%d,%d" % (p['lat_d'], p['lon_d'], p['alt_m'], p['flag_t'] )
    ser_write("UAV#", com)

  # PID config is about to change the sensitivity of the model to changes in attitude
  if type == 'pid':
    com = "%.2f,%.2f,%.4f,%.2f;%.2f,%.2f,%.4f,%.2f;%.2f,%.2f,%.4f,%.2f;%.2f,%.2f,%.4f,%.2f;%.2f,%.2f,%.4f,%.2f;%.2f,%.2f,%.2f,%.2f,%.2f" % (
      p['p_rkp'], p['p_rki'], p['p_rkd'], p['p_rimax'],
      p['r_rkp'], p['r_rki'], p['r_rkd'], p['r_rimax'],
      p['y_rkp'], p['y_rki'], p['y_rkd'], p['y_rimax'],
      p['t_rkp'], p['t_rki'], p['t_rkd'], p['t_rimax'],
      p['a_rkp'], p['a_rki'], p['a_rkd'], p['a_rimax'],
      p['p_skp'], p['r_skp'], p['y_skp'], p['t_skp'], p['a_skp'] )
    ser_write("PID#", com)

  # This section is about correcting drifts while model is flying (e.g. due to imbalances of the model)
  if type == 'cmp':
    com = "%.2f,%.2f" % (p['r'], p['p'])
    ser_write("CMP#", com)

  # With this section you may start the calibration of the gyro again
  if type == 'gyr':
    com = "%d" % (p['cal'])
    ser_write("GYR#", com)

  # User interactant for gyrometer calibration
  if type == 'user_interactant':
    bytes = pySerial.write("x") # write a char into the serial device
    pySerial.flushInput()

  # Ping service for calculating the latency of the connection
  if type == 'ping':
    com = '{"type":"pong","v":%d}' % (p['v'])
    udp_write(com, udp_clients)

def recv_thr():                                                         # recv_thr() is used to catch sensor data
  global udp_clients
  ser_msg = None

  while pySerial is not None:
    if not pySerial.readable() or not pySerial.inWaiting() > 0:
      continue

    try:
      THR_LOCK.acquire()
      ser_msg = pySerial.readline().strip()                           # Remove newline character '\n'
      THR_LOCK.release()
    except serial.SerialTimeoutException as e:
      logging.error("Read timeout on serial port")
    except serial.SerialException as e:
      logging.error("Read exception on serial port")
    else:
      try:
        p = json.loads(ser_msg)
      except (ValueError, KeyError, TypeError):
        #print ("JSON format error: %s" % ser_msg)                       # Print everything what is not a valid JSON string to console
        ser_msg = '{"type":"NOJSON","data":"%s"}' % ser_msg
      finally:
        udp_write(ser_msg, udp_clients)

def trnm_thr():                                                         # trnm_thr() sends commands to Arduino
  global udp_clients
  udp_client = None

  while pySerial is not None:
    if not pySerial.writable():
      continue

    try:
      udp_msg, udp_client = udp_sock.recvfrom(512)                      # Wait for UDP packet from ground station
    except socket.timeout:
      logging.error("Write timeout on socket")                          # Log the problem
    else:
      if udp_client is not None:
        udp_clients.add(udp_client)
      try:
        p = json.loads(udp_msg)                                # parse JSON string from socket
      except (ValueError, KeyError, TypeError):
        logging.debug("JSON format error: " + udp_msg.strip() )
      else:
        make_command(p)

def main():
  recv=threading.Thread(target=recv_thr)
  trnm=threading.Thread(target=trnm_thr)
  recv.start()
  trnm.start()

pySerial = init_serial()
if pySerial is None:
  print ("Could not open any serial port. Exit script.")
  sys.exit(0)
main()
```